# Deploying .vbhtml on Local IIS Installation

Tags: sql-server, iis, vb.net

I've come into a company that has been using asp.net for some web applications stored on our local servers. There's no current programmer, so I've used what knowledge I have to build a new feature using MebMatrix Razor VB.NET pages and our current SQL Server database. I have to migrate the project over to a local server running IIS to deploy it.

I don't want to use the WebMatrix Web Deploy feature or anything, I'd rather just move the files over manually and have them run. I assume that IIS just needs to be configured to process .vbhtml file extensions. My understanding is that you don't have to build your solution with this method, as you do with ASP. Does anybody know how to do this, or where I might find a good tutorial?

Answer (score 2):

I use the Publish solution, File Copy option and push to a shared drive for deployment.  I find it works quite well in most small development servers.  You could also publish locally and then move those files across manually.

Which version of IIS are you using?  With version 6.0 there are some special configurations needed.  Does the IIS handler mapppings have an entry for .vbhtml?

Comment: Yes, we're using IIS v6.0. There are no current entries for .vbhtml. My current thought is that I will create a new web page in IIS (which currently serves our intranet, etc.), create a handler for the file extensions, publish locally and manually move the pages in. Will that work fine? Anything I'm missing?

Comment: The deploy scenario sounds good.  I would suggest researching using Razor on IIS 6.0 a little more.  There are some tricks to use extensionless URLs and it will take a little more configuration than II 7.0, which knows a lot more about MVC / Razor than 6.0.